# SQL Server Cannot Build Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

I'm using

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Enterprise SP1: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) Version 13.0.4411.0

and I have an extremely odd problem I don't know how to solve.  I have an (admittedly fairly large) query that joins together over 100 tables.  I wrote the original a while back and have run the query many times with the join on the 100+ tables, but I wanted to speed it up, so I spent a lot of time tuning it, changing all the LEFT JOINs to INNER JOINS and decoding all range-joins into exact values for matches and adding appropriate covering indexes, etc.  The joins are built via dynamic SQL, so the number of joins is inexact, and my testing for this query-tuning had fewer joined tables (63).  With the 63-table join I was very successful at speeding up the code; it is running at a fraction of the time the original took.  But when I implemented the code and tried to run the analagous 100+ table join query, SQL just runs forever (it used to take a few minutes, now I had to kill it after a full day running).

Nothing that I changed would logically make the code slower.  I added some useful unique covering indexes, changed some range joins to exact match joins, like
`A.Field1 between B.FieldA and B.FieldB` to `A.Field1=B.Field1`

And changed all the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s (data was cleaned up such that all rows will have a match in all tables, so the "LEFT" was no longer necessary).

Normally this is fine...SQL occasionally does unexpected things..., I can generate the estimated execution plan and try to figure out what went awry.  But SQL straight-up can't generate the query execution plan for the query.  It runs forever.  I've tried updating statistics and running with (QUERYTRACEON 9481) to use the old execution plan compiler, but neither helped.

Here's the crazy part: after a lot of testing I am fairly certain it is *only* the execution plan that is taking a long time, and that the actual code execution is extremely fast.  Manually removing joins until it works, I got it to generate the execution plan after a few hours.  Running that same code takes the same amount of time as just generating the estimated execution plan.  The plan is significantly simpler and costs WAY less than the old version with the LEFT JOINs and BETWEEN statements (which, I'll note, runs in under 5 minutes). 
In terms of "Query Cost" if I generate the execution plan for both, 98% of the cost is on the old code and 2% is on the new code.  But the old plan generates in a few seconds, and I can't even get the plan to generate for the new more efficient code with all the joins included.

I've never run into a situation like this, and I'm sort of at a brick wall for how to debug...I don't know how to speed up SQL's execution planner.  This is beyond my expertise.  If it were just an issue of the query being too complex, I think the original code would be seeing this same issue, as it is a lot more complex all around.  It seems to be something else going on, like a bug that only applies to a lot of inner joins but not a lot of left joins or...I have no idea...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*I have a query that joins together over 100 tables*"  Don't do this, it's a bad thing.  The problem isn't your SQL code, it's the data design.  Any design where you have to join together 100 tables is bad and almost certainly not relational.  The way to fix this is to change the data design to be more relational.

Answer (score 0):

Use Live Query Statistics instead
[image]